# Assigning the answer of sin function to the term sin(X) in prolog

Tags: prolog

I wrote a Prolog program to solve simple trigonometric equations. I wrote it to get the value of a trigonometric function. For example, I can obtain the value of `sin(45)`, but I can't assign the value of `sin(45)` to the term `sin(45)`. I tried the `=,==,=:=` operators, but they didn't work. Actually, I want to pass the value of `sin(45)` to the next codes of the program instead of the term `sin(45)`.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied and understand that values can't be assigned to a term using `=`, `==` or `=:=` like procedural languages. When we use this operators prolog just compares the two values. Therefore, we should pass the 
value as a parameter. As an example,

```
isolax(1,sin(U) = V,U = R):-
    getasin(V,R).   

getatan(X,R):-R is atan(X).
```

Even though we don't define the facts or rules for obtaining sin,cos,tan, prolog answers for sin, cos, tan automatically.

Comment: This isn't a totally accurate answer. The `=/2` operator will *unify* the two arguments. It can have the effect of comparing, but it also can have the effect of assigning. The purpose of `is/2` is specifically for arithmetic expressions on the right being assigned to the variable on the left.

Answer (score 4):

arithmetic is carried on by some specialized builtins, like [is](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28is%29/2)/2, or (<)/2, that evaluate their right hand term as an *expression*, and unify the numeric value with their left hand side. The most common usage is assigning a value to a *free* variable, like in

```
?- X is sin(pi/2).
X = 1.0.
```

note the argument of sin/1 it's in radians. After the evaluation, you pass the variable, now bound to a numeric value, down to next code.

Answer (score 1):

Compound terms in prolog ("functors" or "structures") has no any numeric "values".
Prolog arithmetic engine doesn't "assign" calculated value to such a term, it just use the calculated value as an argument 
in outer operation or bounds the calculated value to a variable (as "is" builtin predicate does)

```
Y is sin(45), ... % Y is now now bound to the numeric result of sin(45), do with Y what you whant
```

If you want not to forget the genesis of the value of sin(45),
you can create another term with additional parameters, for example

```
Y is sin(45), MyTerm=funcresult(sin,45,Y),  ... % then pass MyTerm wherever you whant or return it to the caller
```

The consumer of MyTerm can then unify

```
MyTerm= funcresult(F,X,Y),
```

and obtain also the function name (F=sin) and the argument (X=45) along with the result itself (Y)

you can even

```
assert(funcresult(sin,X,Y))
```

and provide a database for all already calculated function values (don't forget

```
:-dynamic(funcresult/3).
```

directive in this case).

Also note,  sin() usually accepts radians, not grades, so sin(45) perhaps yields something you don't expect